# How to destructure nested object that might be undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns an object like the following:

```
{
    data: {key1: value1, ...},
    errors: [...]
}
```

I can extract `key1` with the following:

```
const { data: { key1 }} = myFunction()
```

However, sometimes `data` is undefined which causes the destructuring to fail.

I've looked at the [destructuring examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#examples) and haven't been able to figure out how to pull out `key1` when `data` might be undefined.

Is there a way to assign a default value of `{}` to `data` when performing the destructuring so that it doesn't fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a default object.

```js
const
    myFunction = () => ({}),
    { data: { key1 } = {} } = myFunction();

console.log(key1);
```